# Why is taper given to the top of the steel vessels?

Tags: pressure, stress-strain

[image: A pressure vessel]
In many form of liquid storage vessels, a taper or something similar to it is always provided.
The head of a pressure vessel is connected to the main body mostly using hemispherical or tapered portion.
Is it provided to give more strength and reduce stress?
(In my opinion, stress would increase more).
What's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dished heads on round pressure tanks provide excellent strength and durability. If pressure tanks had flat ends or sides, the material would have to be much thicker to withstand the stress. With flat ends constant pressure changes would bow thinner material back and forth creating fatigue, or stress cracks eventually.

Comment: Why flat ends experience more pressure? Can you explain the last line a more? Thanks.

Comment: @BJKShah Not more pressure, more flexing from pressure changes, a dished head keeps basically the same shape during pressure changes, only stretching slightly with increased pressure. A flat plate would bulge outwards with positive pressure, and bulge inwards with negative pressure, creating greater material fatigue. If the pressure were enough to permanently bend the material, then you would have a dished end anyway.